# jasper report locale wise country name

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports

How to show a country name as per particular report locale's language?

I stored only country codes in database. When display list of country I use following code

```
new Locale("", $F{country_code}).getDisplayCountry(new Locale($P{REPORT_LOCALE}))
```

But it not working getting an error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The constructor Locale(Locale) is undefined
```

Is there any way to display a country name as per report language?

Answer (score 0):

Correct code should like bellow

```
new Locale("", $F{country_code}).getDisplayCountry($P{REPORT_LOCALE})
```

`$P{REPORT_LOCALE}` returns locale object.